# How to solve this integral (delta function)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \bigg(a+\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^2 \delta\big(a^2-(a+x)^2\big)
$$
here $\delta(x)$ is a Dirac delta function. According to Mathematica, the answer is $\frac{a^2}{2|a|}$. I tried to solve it using the method of substitution. Put $u=(a+x)^2\to x=\sqrt{u}-a$. And
$$
\frac{du}{dx}=2(a+x) \to \frac{du}{2(a+x)}=dx
$$
so, the integral becomes
$$
I=\int du\frac{1}{2(a+\sqrt{u}-a)} \bigg(a+\frac{\sqrt{u}-a}{2}\bigg)^2 \delta\big(a^2-u\big)
\\
I=\int du\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} \frac{1}{4}\bigg(a+\sqrt{u}\bigg)^2 \delta\big(a^2-u\big)
\\
I=\frac{1}{8\sqrt{a^2}} \bigg(a+\sqrt{a^2}\bigg)^2 
\\
I=\frac{4a^2}{8a} =\frac{a}{2}
$$
But, the correct answer is $\frac{a^2}{2|a|}$. Can someone please help me, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the small delta?

Comment: @aliberro $\delta(x)$ is a Dirac delta function

Comment: Your answer differs from Mathematica when $a < 0$.  So try doing the case $a=-1$ and see what you get: yours or Mathematica's.

Comment: $\delta(f(x))=\frac{1}{|f'(x_1)|}\delta(x-x_1)+\frac{1}{|f'(x_2)|}\delta(x-x_2)+ ...$,
where $x_1, x_2, ...$ - zeros of $f(x)$ on the interval of integration

Comment: You also should have taken $u=|a|$, not $u=a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}I~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x \bigg(a+\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^2 \delta\big(a^2-(a+x)^2\big)\cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x \bigg(a+\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^2 \delta\big(x(x+2a)\big)\cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x \bigg(a+\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^2\bigg( \frac{\delta(x)}{|x+2a|} +\frac{\delta(x+2a)}{|x|}\bigg)\cr
~=~&\frac{a^2}{|2a|}+0\cr
~=~&\frac{|a|}{2}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that (assuming $a\in\mathbb R$):
$$a>0\qquad\frac{a^2}{2|a|}=\frac{|a|^2}{2|a|}=\frac{|a|}{2}$$
$$a<0\qquad \frac{a^2}{2|a|}=\frac{|a|}{2}$$
whilst your answer will be $<0\forall a<0$

To convince yourself this is the case, let $a>0$ and $b=-a$ and substitute in, then make the substitution $X=-x$. You will see that this takes you back to the original integral and hence $I(a)=I(-a)$